# What is default WSO2IS user session timeout period

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

What is default WSO2IS user session timeout period. Is it possible to extend user session timeout period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default **idle session timeout** period is 15 minutes according to [1]. You can configure it tenant-wise by referring to the steps in [2].

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-session-timeout/#idle-session-time-out

[2] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-session-timeout/#configuration

Comment: I understood. Thank you